# Unable to fail Azure DevOps Release Pipeline when Azure WebJob fails to start/run

Tags: azure-devops, azure-webjobs

What I'm looking for:

- How can we integrate into our Release Pipeline an automated solution for knowing if a new WebJob deploy entered the running status within 'X' period of time?

More Details:

We are using Azure DevOps Release Pipelines with the AzureRMWebAppDelopyment@4 task. We are able to deploy our Azure WebJob to staging and to production environments.

Recently we discovered that our WebJob had not actually started because of some bad code. Due to the nature of the WebJob it was not something we could easily identify in staging. We deployed the bad code to production and days later, due to bad alerting, learned the WebJob was not running and our queue was severely backed up.

This issue is that we want/need our release pipeline to report failures to start for each WebJob. APIs use HealthChecks to verify a deployment started up, is healthy, and otherwise actually good to go. We need to inspect the status of the WebJob during our release pipeline so the pipeline fails so we don't think everything is working when it's not.

In our research we've found we could potentially use Kudu, but how to get that working as part of the release pipeline has proven unfindable for us so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After combining ideas from multiple sources we came up with this solution:

In the desired Azure Release Pipeline in the desired stage add an Azure CLI task. This task can accept an inline PowerShell script or a path to a PowerShell script. **Choose your own adventure.** We chose to create a `CheckWebJobStatus.ps1` with the included script (below) and exposed it as an artifact available to our Azure Release Pipeline.

*What this PowerShell script does in short:*
It checks the target WebJob's status up to 10 times (configurable via `$totalRuns`) waiting 5 seconds between checks and waits for 3 consecutive `Running` status reports.

```bsh
param(
    $resourceGroup,
    $appServiceName,
    $jobName,
    $totalRuns = 10
)

Write-Host "Checking status of $jobName in $resourceGroup/$appServiceName"

$consecutiveRunningStatuses = 0
if ($totalRuns -lt 3) {
    Write-Error "totalRuns must be 3 or greater"
    exit 1
}

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $totalRuns; $i++) {
    $jobs = (az webapp webjob continuous list --name $appServiceName --resource-group $resourceGroup | ConvertFrom-Json)

    foreach ($job in $jobs) {
        if ($job.name -eq "$appServiceName/$jobName") {
            if ($job.status -eq "Running") {
                Write-Host "$jobName is running! Attempt $i"
                $consecutiveRunningStatuses++

                if ($consecutiveRunningStatuses -eq 3) {
                    Write-Host "$jobName is running $consecutiveRunningStatuses times in a row! We assume that means it is stable."
                    exit 0
                }
            }
            else {
                Write-Host "$jobName status is $($job.status). Attempt $i"
                $consecutiveRunningStatuses = 0
            }
        }
    }

    if ($i -ne ($totalRuns - 1)) {
        Start-Sleep 5
    }
}

Write-Host "$jobName failed to start after $totalRuns checks"
exit 1
```

*Why 3 consecutive `Running` status reports?*
Because Azure WebJobs status reporting is not reliable. When a WebJob first deploys it enters the `Starting` status then the `Running` status. So far that seems good. However, if there is a fatal error on startup like a missing dependency, the job then enters the `Pending Restart` status. In our observation Azure either automatically tries to start the WebJob again or the status gets weird and gets reported erroneously as being in the `Running` status. The WebJob will then re-enter the `Pending Restart` status and remain at that status until the next explicit attempt to deploy or start it. In our observations we did not see a failing WebJob remain in the `Running` status for more then 2 consecutive reports 5 seconds apart or, in other words, within any 15 second window. Therefore in the script we are assuming, for now, that if we get 3 consecutive `Running` status reports within 15 seconds the WebJob is assumed to be `Running`.

*Aside - How we did it:*
We created a dedicated DeployTools repo with its own `azure-pipelines.yaml` build configuration which only publishes the folder with that PowerShell file. Then in our desired Azure Release Pipeline we attached the artifacts from the DeployTools build.

Answer (score 0):

You can try do this:

[image: -]

You can create a seprate stage or do it inside you existing. By adding `Agentless job` you can add delay task. After that you can call kudu endpoint to check history of the WebJob (as it is shown [here](https://markheath.net/post/managing-webjobs-with-kudu-api)) for instance. If you don't find satisfying response you can simply end your script with `exit 1` to fail the release.

Here you have an [article about accessing KUDU](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Accessing-the-kudu-service)

and from what [I found](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/2997#issuecomment-504522988):

> Off the top, the MFA is the contract between AAD and User, when it gets to Kudu endpoint, it is just a token. It should just work, IMO.

Comment: So what credentials do we use in our automated process? We have MFA for all accounts required plus you should never use an individual's creds to do an `az login`. Is there a way to use the configured subscriptions in an Azure DevOps PowerShell script as shown by you here?

Comment: @dannydwarren please check my edit. I didn't check this but from what I found KUDU should not be interrupted by MFA.

Comment: Krzysztof Madej thank you for the assistance! Your ideas inspired us to go down the route I posted in the accepted answer. Kudu and publish profile credentials were not a good fit for us in this situation.

Comment: @dannydwarren really appreciate your words! I'm happy you solved your issue!